# GCP Cloud Run Invoke another Projects Cloud function using short-lived credentials via 2 service accounts in separate Projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-iam

I have done the below and it all works to the point of the last token being used to invoke a
cloud function.

I have created a service account (SP), in Project 2, with Service-Account-Token-Creator and Cloud-Functions-Invoker roles. I also have created another service account (sc), in Project 1, with Service-Account-Token-Creator. I edited the IAM bindings of SP to allow SC the ability to create short-lived credentials via the Service-Account-Token-Creator role.

This code below, in Project 1, is running on CloudRun and with the service account, SC as the default service account for the instance.

Not sure what is really wrong, but all I'm trying to do is impersonate SP and then be able to invoke the cloud function in SP's account.

Any assistance with what is going wrong would help.

```
      import { Compute } from 'google-auth-library';

      const client = new Compute({
        // Specifying the service account email is optional.
        serviceAccountEmail:
          'sc@swaymeebusinessapp.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
      });

      const res = await client.request<{
        accessToken: string;
        expireTime: string;
      }>({
        url:
          'https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/sp@<project-di>.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken',
        method: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
          delegates: [],
          scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
          lifetime: '300s',
        }),
      });

      request.http.headers.set(
        'Authorization',
        `Bearer ${res.data.accessToken}`
      );
```

The error I received when invoking the cloud function in project 2 is

```
https://us-central1-project-2.cloudfunctions.net/project-2-alpha-TestFunction: 401: Unauthorized
```

Comment: Could you please post any error logs when you try to invoke the cloud function is project 2?

Comment: Can you precise at which level have you grant the "token creator" and the "cloud invoker" roles? I mean: You grant "sc" token creator at..... project 1 level, project 2 level,  SP level???

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I'm not sure what you mean at which level did i grant the token creator role. I granted SP cloud functions invoker and Service Account token Creator roles. while also granting SC Service Account token Creator role via updating the iam policy

Comment: Why do you need to impersonate the service account? And I'm quite lost with SP, SC, sc.... Which is where, with which role, and how do you have granted the role?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I need to impersonate because it is a private cloud function endpoint in service 2. Got it. To further clarify. SP is in project 2 with ServiceTokenCreator, CloudFunctionCreator Roles. SC is in project1 with ServiceTokenCreator Role. Not quite sure I follow your last question.

Comment: Wait, I think there is a misunderstanding here. `I need to impersonate because it is a private cloud function endpoint in service 2`. Private cloud function means (for you) a function that require authentication? or it's more than that?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes, sorry should have been more clear. Not behind a VPC or anything just a function that requires authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply grant the service account SC of the project1 on the Cloud Functions of the project2. SP is useless, impersonification also!

- Get the email of SC
- Go to your Cloud Functions list page and select your function (checkbox)

  - Click on "show info panel" in the upper right corner
  - Paste the SC email in the member section
  - Select Cloud Functions Invoker as role.
    [image]
- save

That's all. *You grant the SC of the project1, with the role Function.invoker at the level of the Cloud Functions of the project2*

This definition is important. If you create another function, SC won't be able to reach it, because you grant the role only at the function level.

If you want to grant access to all the CLoud Function of the project2 (that is not recommended), you can do it like this

Instead of selecting your Cloud Functions in the project2, go to the IAM page of the project2 (here your are at project level) and click on Add Member (top of the page), paste the SC email and add the role CLoud FUnction invoker.

Comment: interesting...I'll give this a try, and curious, when is the proper time to use service account impersonation.

Comment: I use impersonation to protect production. I mean, in production, no user account have access to it. They have to gain access by using impersonation of existing service account. All user accounts can impersonate all service account. We grant user only at the service account level. (Yes, the service account is a strange thing: you can use it for authentication, but also, you can use it as resource and grant role (here token creator) at its level...)

Comment: At the end, the service account is like an email, like your user account. You don't belong to a project, just to an organisation, but you still have access to the projects because you have been granted on them. It's the same logic with email (service account or other user account outside your organisation)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I just overcomplicated things.

Answer (score 1):

I think at least part of your issue is you are calling the IAM method:
`generateAccessToken`

to get your short lived token, then using that as an auth header when calling the Cloud Function - but for the invoker IAM use, you need to use an OIDC ID Token retrieved from a call to

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/generateIdToken

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to give it a try.